# SQL Statement WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I am currently have two tables in my database. One is `Applicants`, another being `ProgrammeDetail`. In `ProgrammeDetail`, I capture the `minimum required applicant`. So when `Applicant` sign up for a programme, they will be tied to the `ProgrammeID`.

However, when I do my SQL statement, using `INNERJOIN` and `WHERE` clause, I kept getting error.

**programmeDetail** table with sample data:

```
-------------------------------------------
|  programmeID  |   programmeRequirement  |
-------------------------------------------
|   P01         |          20             |
-------------------------------------------
```

**applicant** table with sample data:

```
-----------------------------------
|   applicantID  |   programmeID  |
-----------------------------------
|    A001        |      P01       |
-----------------------------------
|    A002        |      P01       |
-----------------------------------
```

Desired output:

```
-------------------------------------------
|  programmeID  |   programmeRequirement  |
-------------------------------------------
|   P01         |          20             |
-------------------------------------------
```

Because there's only 2 applicants for `P01` and minimum requirement is 20 applicants. Thus `P01` will retrieved.

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM programmeDetail pD
INNER JOIN applicant appl
    ON pD.programmeID = appl.programmeID
WHERE COUNT(appl.applicantID) < pD.programmeRequirement
```

Error:

> is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please show a) table structure, b) sample data, and c) your desired output.  This question is currently unclear.

Comment: Don't you need to use alias in where as well ?

Comment: also put what error you are getting. unclear.

Comment: I think we cannot compare count like that...aggregate operations should be combined with group by and having clause

Comment: You  need to use aggregates in having clause with group by. Your query is incorrect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated with whatever you asked for.

Comment: @Geeky Updated my question. Do have a look.. thanks for the help if can..

Comment: @satya.j Updated my question. Do have a look.. thanks for the help if can..

Comment: @TechBreak Updated my question. Do have a look.. thanks for the help if can..

Comment: Your sample data still leaves the question unclear IMO.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have a programme ongoing, and this programme requires at least 20 signups. So currently I only have 2 signups, thus, I want to grab those programme that are not having enough signups.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following, I have tried with MySQL and it works with your desired output. I have added only columns you need in result.

```
SELECT pD.programmeID
       pD.programmeRequirement
FROM programmeDetail pD
INNER JOIN applicant appl
    ON pD.programmeID = appl.programmeID
GROUP BY pd.programmeID
HAVING COUNT(*) < 20
```

Comment: @Arane i have tried in MySQL and it works. I have updated query with columns you need in your result.

Comment: @TechBreak Your query was all over the place, and MySQL is the least strict database out there.  For certain, the query would not run on any other RDBMS.  I made an update which might work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm having this error now.. `Column 'pD.programmeRequirement' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Add pD.programmeRequirement in group by?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agree. 
arane did that solved your issue?